# Folder for orange widget in local machine

Tags: widget, orange

Apologies if the question sounds silly, am a newbie to programming. I am trying to go through the tutorial for writing a demo widget: https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-development/en/latest/tutorial.html

it says that the layout should be as follows:
orange-demo/
setup.py
orangedemo/
**init**.py
OWDataSamplerA.py

but were exactly should I place the orange-demo folder in my local machine. I am using orange/miniconda on windows.

Can anybody just suggest me the right location?